# laravel - passing data to class-based component, without @props

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-components

I have this component:

```
class CategorySelect extends Component
{

    public $id_name, $selected;

    public function __construct($selected=-1, $id_name="default_id")
    {
        $this->id_name = $id_name;
        $this->selected = $selected;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.category-select', ['categories' => Category::all()]);
    }
}


<select name="{{ $id_name }}" id="{{ $id_name }}">
    @foreach ($categories as $c)
        @php
            $s = $c->id == $selected ? 'selected=selected' : '';
        @endphp
        <option {{ $s }} value="{{ $c->id }}">{{ $c->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I use it like this:

```
<x-category-select selected="old('category_id', $article->category_id)" 
                   id_name="category_id"></x-category-select>
```

The `$selected` is passed and working, but the `$id_name` stays in its default value from the constructor.
changing to `:id_name="category_id"` fails with `Undefined constant "category_id"`

What is the proper way to do it, without `@props()` (I'm using class based components and not anonymous components for that reason, among others..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will stumble on it in the future - the issue was the naming convention. when the variable names changed to `camelCase` - it worked.

`$id_name` changed to `$idName` and it worked